Delphi Interface Automatic Reference Counting
Say I have an interface and a concrete type implementing that interface, like:
  IMyBuilderIntf = interface
    function Build(): String;
  end;

//...

  TMyConcreteType = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyBuilderIntf)
    //...
    function Build(): String;
  end;

And a function that accepts this interface as a parameter such as:
  function MyFunctionUsingInterface(AParam: IMyBuilderIntf): Boolean;
  begin
    //...
    AParam.Build();
    //...
  end;

And in my client code uses it in the following way:
function EntryPoint(): Integer;
var
  concreteBldr: TMyConcreteType;
begin
  // Operates with specific functions declared and defined in TMyConcreteType.
  MyFunctionUsingInterface(concreteBldr); // <<<<<<<
end;

Will the object stored in concreteBldr have its memory managed? Any object that becomes accessed through an interface becomes automatically managed and this behavior depends on the type (concrete or abstract) it was previously declared?


Will the object stored in concreteBldr have its memory managed?

In this example, yes. And because of that, the code you have shown is potentially dangerous, depending on what the rest of EntryPoint() looks like.
Because concreteBldr is declared as its implementation class type and not as its interface type, then initially its reference count will be 0, then it will be increased to 1 when passed to MyFunctionUsingInterface() (since the parameter is not const), and then fall to 0 when MyFunctionUsingInterface() exits, thus freeing the object immediately.  If you then try to continue accessing concreteBldr afterwards, the code will have undefined behavior and likely crash.
This is why it is dangerous to mix object references and interfaces references to the same object.
To mitigate this, you can either:

make the parameter const:
function MyFunctionUsingInterface(const AParam: IMyBuilderIntf): Boolean;

But note this can introduce a different problem if you are not careful. For example:
MyFunctionUsingInterface(TMyConcreteType.Create); // this will leak!!
MyFunctionUsingInterface(TMyConcreteType.Create as IMyBuilderIntf); // but this will not :)


change the type of concreteBldr to IMyBuilderIntf, and then cast it only when you need to access members that are specific to TMyConcreteType:
function EntryPoint(): Integer;
var
  concreteBldr: IMyBuilderIntf;
begin
  concreteBldr := TMyConcreteType.Create;
  // or: either way works fine...
  // concreteBldr := TMyConcreteType.Create as IMyBuilderIntf;
  ...
  TMyConcreteType(concreteBldr).DoSomething;
  // or: (concreteBldr as TMyConcreteType).DoSomething;
  ...
  MyFunctionUsingInterface(concreteBldr);
end;

With this model, you can still maintain some control over when the object is freed. Simply release your reference to it explicitly if you don't want to wait for the creating function to exit, eg:
function EntryPoint(): Integer;
var
  concreteBldr: IMyBuilderIntf;
begin
  concreteBldr := TMyConcreteType.Create;
  ...
  MyFunctionUsingInterface(concreteBldr);
  concreatBldr := nil; // <--
  ...
end;




Any object that becomes accessed through an interface becomes automatically managed

It may or may not, it depends on how you use the interface, and which operations you perform that do or do not invoke reference counting semantics.  A non-const interface parameter DOES. A const interface parameter, and an object reference, DOES NOT.

Thank you for your answer. In this specific case, it's indeed the behavior I wanted: I set the fields into the object, send to the function that builds the query and executes it. It's not supposed to be accessed after being passed to that function. It was accidental tho lol

@ArthurAraujo Even if this is the behavior you want in this specific case, I'd say it would still be better (more standard and safer) to declare the variable as concreteBldr: IMyBuilderIntf. It's really the normal way and best practice: stick to only interfaces, and not mix. Your object will still be automatically freed, just a bit later. If it's declared an object, it will be freed when the function (with non-const parameter) returns. If it's declared an interface, it will be freed when the code block where it is declared exits.

@ArthurAraujo You should not rely on intermittent reference counting when interface reference is being passed as parameter to manage that instance memory. You should use write your code the way it is shown in EntryPoint from Remy's answer. In other words, you should have a strong (interface) reference to that instance which will properly initialize reference counting mechanism and predictably manage that instance memory and then typecast to object is necessary. Anything else will lead to extremely fragile code that can accidentally break if someone changes the function parameter to const

Now, you can say that this will not happen, but it is customary for functions that take interfaces as parameters to have those declared as const because it is rarely necessary to trigger reference counting during a function call, and having const parameter is faster because it avoids unnecessary reference counting. You function where interface reference is not declared as const is not typical one and someone might "fix" your function declaration which would introduce bugs if you leave your code as-is.

There is nothing automatic or magical about interface reference counting in Delphi; the "automatic" memory management is the result of collaboration between the compiler (injecting calls to AddRef and Release according to scoping and other rules) and the implementation of a class.  Any class which descends from TInterfacedObject will be Free'd when ref count = 0 by the implementation of Release on TInterfacedObject.  In other (admittedly rare cases), other classes may behave differently.
